# BeautifulSoup identify the surrounding characters of an attribute

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

as simple as that i would like to know whether an attribute is surrounded by ' ' or " " or not surrounded at all.
for example:

```
html = """<input class="form-control" name='searchString' type=text value= "myString"/>"""
```

looping on the attribute values of this tag will return the value without the surrounding character which in name's case its '', in type teres no surrounding character, and in value its "".
so is there any way to do it with beautifulsoup or should I use regex / parse the string myself ?
thanks in advance.

Comment: The surrounding quote makes no difference whatsoever so there is no reason to try to find out what it is.

Comment: well for me it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the following regex is used by `html.parser` to extract element attributes

```
html = """<input class="form-control" name='searchString' type=text value= "myString"/>"""

attrfind = re.compile(
    r'((?<=[\'"\s/])[^\s/>][^\s/=>]*)(\s*=+\s*'
    r'(\'[^\']*\'|"[^"]*"|(?![\'"])[^>\s]*))?(?:\s|/(?!>))*')
attrs = attrfind.findall(html)

for attr in attrs:
    print('{}: {}'.format(attr[0], attr[2]))
```

Results

```
class: "form-control"
name: 'searchString'
type: text
value: "myString"
```

Answer (score 0):

The parsers will "correct" the markup that you provide to BeautifulSoup.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = """<input class="form-control" name='searchString' type=text value= "myString"/>"""
print(BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml'))
print(BeautifulSoup(html,'html5lib'))
print(BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser'))
#<html><body><input class="form-control" name="searchString" type="text" value="myString"/></body></html>
#<html><head></head><body><input class="form-control" name="searchString" type="text" value="myString"/></body></html>
#<input class="form-control" name="searchString" type="text" value="myString"/>
```

As you can see all the quotes are now `"` .To answer your question - I don't think it is possible with BeautiifulSoup. It is possible with regex (you will have to apply it to your request response).